# Are there insects or spiders on Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

At the end of "Homestead," as Neelix is preparing to permanently leave the ship, Tuvok stops him. Before he's able to speak, Tuvok looks down and grinds his foot into the ground for a few seconds. Is he smashing a bug?

This is but one piece of circumstantial evidence. There may be more, but I'm unsure of them presently.

Comment: You should provide video if it's that relevant to the question.

Comment: To be honest, it is probably just a stereotypical gesture that people make when they are coy or nervous about sharing something intimate.   Like is Tuvok about tell him his going to miss him??

Comment: Actually, I just looked it up and it jogged my memory -- see my answer.

Comment: Is the question here asking whether there are insects on Voyager, or is it asking what Tuvok was doing in that scene? Those are different questions, and as demonstrated below, they have separate answers. So I think it should be edited to clarify which one is really being asked. (Probably the latter, given that it's the one that has already been answered)

Comment: I was asking if there are insects or spiders on Voyager. One piece of evidence that I provided that I thought supported my position was Tuvok's grinding of his foot into the ground at the close of "Homestead." I thought perhaps he was letting Neelix know that he'd make sure that no insects would get anywhere near the dining hall: he'd grind them into the ground! I figured this was his going-away gift to the Talaxian---knowledge that the kitchen would be kept clean.

Comment: Is this question asking "are there insects on Voyager at all" or "are there _loose_ insects, outside the lab"?

Comment: @HamSandwich Then why did you accept TPMs answer which doesn't answer the question?

Comment: The question is actually ***"Why does Tuvok do this with his foot?"*** but OP has phrased it oddly, creating an additional question

Comment: Why on earth would Tuvok be squishing a bug in that moment??

Comment: I had to reverse your edit, Carrot. Episode titles are not italicized.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there are insects on Voyager. They are "Spawn Beetles" used in the Hydroponics Bay for pollinating flowers.

Kes chows down on a handful in the episode Elogium, where she's in breeding frenzy.

[image: Kes, just about to eat bugs]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps Tuvok was crushing one of these.

Comment: No! He was dancing, like ThePopMachine answered. So, yes there are bugs on Voyager, and No, Tuvok was not squashing one when farewelling Neelix.

Answer (score 45):

The scene you're describing is a follow up to this exchange at the beginning of the episode.

> NEELIX: And now, for some more of Zefram Cochrane's favourite music. Hey, come on, Mister Vulcan. 
>   TUVOK: Vulcans do not dance.  
>  
>   NEELIX: But it's tradition.  
>   TUVOK: There is no tradition, Mister Neelix. This ceremony is entirely your invention. 
>   JANEWAY: This is an official ship function, Commander. Don't make me order you to dance.

Later, when Neelix is leaving, Tuvok is doing a little mini twist (the dance) to show Neelix that he respects him and will miss him by putting himself out and to some degree embarrassing himself by dancing.

So....  bottom line, that particular scene is no evidence of whether there are insects on Voyager.

Comment: But to directly answer the title question, yes there are bugs on Voyager. They're used in the hydroponic garden as seen in the episode Elogium.

Comment: The best dancing a Vulcan can bring himself to muster up

Answer (score 8):

There's also an occasion when Voyager becomes infested with ["Photonic fleas"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Photonic_flea).

> Photonic fleas were tiny flying insects native to the Delta Quadrant. They built flimsy webs and fed on plasma particles.
>
> A mating pair of photonic fleas were inadvertently brought aboard the USS Voyager in 2376 within a shipment of amber spice. The insects nested near a plasma conduit, causing a momentary loss of sensor resolution whenever they tapped into the conduit for nourishment. They were moved to a safe location after their discovery. (VOY: "The Voyager Conspiracy")

Comment: Please don't provide what is essentially a link only answer. I've added the information in from the link so your answer has a bit more meat to it.

Comment: "moved to a safe location"??  Eyeroll.